# How to add html to blueimp gallery title element

Tags: javascript, carousel, image-gallery, blueimp

I am using a blueimp gallery carousel and would like to style the title element, so that certain words are bold or a different colour, or even links. I've managed to find a code snippet which allows me to turn the image itself into a link but it's not precisely what I am after.

Is this possible?

**JS:**

```
document.getElementById('links').onclick = function (event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
        link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
        options = {index: link, event: event},
        links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
    blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
};
$(document).ready(function() {

    //BlueImp Carousel
    document.getElementById('links').onclick = function(event) {
        event = event || window.event;
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
            link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
            options = {
                index: link,
                event: event
            },
            links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
        blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
    };

    var title;
    blueimp.Gallery(
        document.getElementById('links').getElementsByTagName('a'), {
            container: '#blueimp-gallery-carousel',
            carousel: true,
            thumbnailIndicators: false,
            transitionSpeed: 400,
            slideshowInterval: 5000,
            clearSlides: true,
            titleElement: 'h3',
            urlProperty: 'link',
            onslidecomplete: function(index, slide) {
                title = $(slide).find("img").attr("title");
                var href = this.list[index].getAttribute('href');
                slide.innerHTML = "<a href='" + href + "' title='" + title + "'>" + slide.innerHTML + "</a>";
            }

        }
    );

});
```

**Relevant HTML:**

```
<div id="blueimp-gallery-carousel" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls blueimp-gallery-carousel karussell">
    <div class="slides"></div>
        <h3 class="title"></h3>
        <a class="prev">&lt;</a>
        <a class="next">&gt;</a>
</div>
<div id="links">
    <a href="link.html" data-link="img.jpg" title="title1">
    </a>
    <a href="link2.html" data-link="img2.jpg" title="title2">
    </a>
</div>
```

**Clarifying example of how I'd like it to look if it were HTML:**

```
<div><img src="carousel of moving images"></div>
<div>Title text <a href="link">with links </a> and <strong>styles</strong>. (moving according to the image)</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I achieved this result by changing 
`blueimp-gallery.js`  line 960 from this:

```
titleElement[0].appendChild(document.createTextNode(text))
```

to this:

```
(titleElement[0]).innerHTML = text
```

Not sure if there is any downside yet, although, would prefer not to edit main source code obviously.